# Difference between vowels

Tags: acoustics

What makes vowels different? I know that depending on the position of tongue and the mouth shape the different vowels can be produced. But what makes vowels different in terms of sound waves?

Comment: I don't know how the answer to your question, but perhaps these links are interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_voice , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonation .

Comment: The question seems legit to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do different letters sound different?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335788/why-do-different-letters-sound-different) Clearly in the realm of physics - Helmholtz was a physicist.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Different [harmonic content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic). Same answer as to the question of why one musical instrument sounds different from another.

Your mouth and throat act as a complicated [resonant cavity](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/resonant-cavity), and changing the shape of it changes which harmonics in your voice are enhanced and which are diminished.

Comment: Yes, this leads to formants https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant One can measure these with spectrogram apps on a mobile phone.